# jQuery and Canvas.toDataURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas, data-url

I'm working on a script, and a small part of that involves taking a canvas and converting it to a downloadable image.  To do this, I do:

```
var thumb_jpeg = thumbnail.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
$("#" + options.dest).attr('src',thumb_jpeg);
```

...where thumbnail is a canvas tag and options.dest is the name of an img id.

This code works perfectly in Chrome, but when I try it in Firefox, Firebug throws up this error:

```
Security error" code: "1000
var thumb_jpeg = thumbnail.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

I would link to the whole script, but everything is hosted on my computer.  Does anyone have any idea what this might mean?

Thanks!
Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it may be because you have it hosted on your computer. Are you working directly from your local filesystem or are you working on a local server like MAMP or WAMP? I had this security code pop up on me before and it was alleviated when I moved my files from my hard drive on to a server.

Comment: Just running it locally, no server (since its just javascript).

Uploaded it to a server, and what do you know...  Problem solved!

Thanks Scott!

Answer (score 2):

Friend, this way works perfectly:

```
document.querySelector('#mycanvas').toDataURL();
```