# Security error" code: "1000 on Firefox with Canvas.toDataURL

Tags: firefox, canvas, data-url

I've got error like [jQuery and Canvas.toDataURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924837/jquery-and-canvas-todataurl)

Some user told that might run it on server 
but
I run it on my server not local

and still got this 'Security error" code: "1000' error.

> Security error" code: "1000
>
> [Break On This Error] data: 'raw='+canvas.toDataURL("image/png", ""),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oh I've found solution 
just change

```
toDataURL('image/png', '')
```

to

```
toDataURL()
```

and it run correctly