# CSS Make text over image more readable

Tags: html, css, overlay

I'm working a few things right now, and this just won't work!

Basically what I'm trying to do is put a black opaque "screen" over my image so it's not as bright and you can read what the text on top of the image says.

Example featured here:

[image]

This is what I have currently.

```
<div class="overlay">
    <span class="front-coffee block"></span>
    <p class="center">Coffee Shop</p>
</div>

div.overlay{background: black; z-index: 5; width:100%; height:100%;}
.block { display: block; }
div.popularCategory p{font-size: 24pt; color: white; margin-top:-50px}
span.front-coffee{background:url('../img/categories/coffee.jpg') no-repeat center; zoom:0.65; width:100%; height:100%; z-index: 4}
```

Comment: try giving the width and height in pixels as 100% would return something else in your case as the parent div's height and width is not specified.

Comment: To no avail, it did not work! I edited my post with the class for the overlay however.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I got you correctly then you can just try blurring the photo a little that the text doesn't show up to the user however this approach and your approach aswell may be changed through firebug or any other thing like that and make the text visible to the user so this is somewhat insecure. The best way I think to fix that is to edit the photo and add the overlay maunally so that no one could ever see the original image.

So here's how to blur the photo([Cross Browser Image Blur with CSS](http://demosthenes.info/blog/534/Cross-browser-Image-Blur-with-CSS)):

```
img {
    width:367;
    height:459px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px); //change the value according to what suits the best
    -moz-filter: blur(3px); //change the value according to what suits the best
    -o-filter: blur(3px); //change the value according to what suits the best
    -ms-filter: blur(3px); //change the value according to what suits the best
    filter: blur(3px); //change the value according to what suits the best
}
```

Comment: That looks excellent! Thank you. I would have edited them manually in Photoshop or something, but I wanted to avoid having to edit 400 photos.

Comment: not really what the OP asked, I see no overlay. And the support for blur is not that great. Consider using an svg filter in stead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803122/filter-blur1px-doesnt-work-in-firefox-ie-and-opera#answer-15813429

Comment: @PeterVR but the OP liked it. :/

Comment: @PeterVR My ultimate goal was to just make the text readable, it did just that. :)

Comment: perhaps you should rephrase the question then ('how to make text on top of an image more readable' or something) so future visitors can benefit from this answer as well. That is what SO is for after all...

Comment: @PeterVR you have enough repo to do that, why aren't you doing it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="front-coffee block">
     <img src='//image goes here' border='0' />
</div>
```

//CSS

```
.front-coffee {
      //Your CSS here
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); //If put against a lighter background, this will give a nice transition effect towards a lighter gray colour. This is absolutely not needed. But I suggest having at least 1 solid layer behind your opaque image.
      }
.front-coffee img {
      opacity: 0.7; // This will ensure that all images will have an opacity set to 70% .
      }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You most likely have the background still set on your span.front-coffee. But I see you've got your answer.