# is the following js code proper, in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

**Site.js**

```
/* blur on modal open, unblur on close */
$('#aboutsbaims').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#mycontent').addClass('blur');
});

$('#aboutsbaims').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#mycontent').removeClass('blur');
});
```

is this code proper ?? it's not working. I have checked the div id names and they are proper. there is not spelling mistake

here is the link to my detailed question. please answer ASAP
[Want to blur the background on twitter-bootstrap modal load. The javascript code is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087261/want-to-blur-the-background-on-twitter-bootstrap-modal-load-the-javascript-code)

Comment: I dont Know .on('why')

Comment: Do you have a proper refrences to the libraries. i mean is there someting which is not loaded.

Comment: @Jai yes. i do. i solved the problem with other method (editing css) but js won't work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(function() { ... });` to make sure all the DOM elements are loaded properly since you've included your `Site.js` in the `<head>` section of your page.

```
$(function() {
    /* blur on modal open, unblur on close */
    $('#aboutsbaims').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#mycontent').addClass('blur');
    });

    $('#aboutsbaims').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#mycontent').removeClass('blur');
    });
});
```

Comment: sir: thank u very very very much.. it helped. i did solve this problem by editing css but now after trying ur solution it worked exactly i wanted. Thank u very very much. thank u.