# How to make Blur Effect working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, filter

I need to create a blur effect that would work also on IE when `position` is set on `relative`, `absolute` atc..
I am not able to make this work.
Here is a sample:  [Sample](http://kod.djpw.cz/brdb-)

It is supposed to be all blurred but it only blurs element with no `position` set.
Works fine in other browsers but not on IE..

Comment: Maybe this will help you 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803122/filter-blur1px-doesnt-work-in-firefox-ie-and-opera

Comment: But this does not solve my problém with the position..

Comment: I have the very same solution as in your link but it just doesnt work when you set position: relative; etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend your blur filter to elements themselves :

```
.blur, /* do you neeed it too for IE ? */
.blur p, /* extra for IE  */
.blur div/* extra for IE  */
 {
-ms-filter: blur(2px); 
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelradius='2', shadowopacity='0.0');
}
```

So maybe the solution is to set the blur filter via class only to childs :), **else filter is applied twice** on non relative elements.
[image: blur with relative childs buggs]

Comment: Thanks. But is there a solution for setting the blur filter on all childs? I mean I would like to get all body element blurred and there might be plenty of elements inside with a complex structure..

Comment: use the joker maybe ? body * {} or body > * {}