# Fix CSS Shadow Issue in Interner Explorer

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I designed featured boxes on a webpage and added a shadow to the bottom using CSS. It looks good in Chrome and Firefox but when I checked on IE 11, it does not look okay.

[image]

The image above is from other browsers and the obe below is the appearance on IE 11.

[image]

I addded the shadow using the CSS code below:

```
.service_group:hover .uk-box-shadow-bottom:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: #000;
    filter: blur(20px);
}
```

Is there a way to get rid of the solid black shadow in IE? I learned I can add a CSS stylesheet for IE and override this CSS code inside. But it seems like that would be overkill. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Hi ! Does it sound like https://stackoverflow.com/q/15803122/4698373 ? If not, please make a little snippet `<>` here to work on this issue :)

Comment: So I guess your problem is that filter isn't supported on IE (see https://caniuse.com/?search=filter). It works OK now on almost every other browser and certainly on the most popular ones. Could you show us relevant HTML as well as CSS, thanks.

Comment: @Philippe, thanks. It looks like the other post is looking for a way to apply the filter to IE. I want to remove it from IE and leave it on others since it does not work on IE by default.  Perharps adding a rule in the CSS (e.g. visibility: hidden or display: none) on the class that will only work for IE?

Comment: I don't know yet any `@media agent` query :( At worst loading a specific patch stylesheet if you detect IE user-agent with rules marked as !important ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get CSS to test whether filter is supported by the browser in modern browsers. @support isn't supported in IE so it just ignores the setting of the background to black so it's there but not seen.

Here's an example snippet - obviously hasn't got all the right sizing that your code will have.

```html
<style>
  .service_group {}
  
  .uk-box-shadow-bottom {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .service_group:hover .uk-box-shadow-bottom:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    /*background: #000;*/
    /*filter: blur(20px);*/
    height: 40px;
  }
  
  @supports (filter: blur()) {
    .service_group:hover .uk-box-shadow-bottom:before {
      background: #000;
      filter: blur(20px);
    }
  }
</style>
<div class="service_group">Just some info so I can hover
  <div class="uk-box-shadow-bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @support is exactly the feature I am looking for and it worked as intended! Strange that I have never come across it until now. Only removed the hover state since the shadow are supposed to appear always for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try box shadow

```
.service_group:hover{
box-shadow: 3px 9px 35px 0px black;
}
```

And can also check how many browsers are supporting this property

https://caniuse.com/?search=box-shadow